Where could I find the configuration files for the `Activities Overview application` and its folder structure?
I'm looking for the configuration files related to the Ubuntu Dash application.  I want to backup the folder structure after customizing my applications in the Activities Overview, but I'm unable to locate which is the relevant config files for them.

I try to find it in Search engine and gnome docs.
I guess it maybe in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell or ~/.confg/gnome-shell. Maybe it's a xml file


Possibly it might be in gsettings/dconf

@muru
Nothing about what I find but thank you try to answer this question. Maybe there have not these files at all.
